# How to convert String to TimeOfDay in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a String, lets say '16:00' and I want to convert it to a `TimeOfDay` type. I checked the documentation and it only provides a converter from `DateTime` to `TimeOfDay`, but I can't find a way to convert from `String` to `TimeOfDay`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this

```
TimeOfDay _startTime = TimeOfDay(hour:int.parse(s.split(":")[0]),minute: int.parse(s.split(":")[1]));
```

This Worked for me..

Comment: That’s true, didn’t think about conversion.

Comment: this doesn't work when you have localizes string. e.g. 9:00 AM

Comment: that doesn't work when we have time in the following format 10:00 PM

Answer (score 39):

like this:

```
TimeOfDay stringToTimeOfDay(String tod) {
  final format = DateFormat.jm(); //"6:00 AM"
  return TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(format.parse(tod));
}
```

Comment: what is 'DateFormat'?

Comment: in this case is a parser format, used to tell "TimeOfDay" how the incoming data should be parsed

Comment: You just saved my hours of coding to get it done

Comment: 'DateFormat' is part of the 'intl' package. Would be nice to add that to the answer.
Package can be found here: https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Comment: Works great. I just had to change mine to DateFormat.Hms() since I am using 24 HOUR time (12:00:00)

Comment: Better approach. Splitting the time string is not useful for 12 hr time. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: This will not work if the string does not have `AM` or `PM`

Answer (score 5):

I use some of the answers here, and doesn't work properly when AM and PM are in the String. Here is my solution.

```
TimeOfDay fromString(String time) {
  int hh = 0;
  if (time.endsWith('PM')) hh = 12;
  time = time.split(' ')[0];
  return TimeOfDay(
    hour: hh + int.parse(time.split(":")[0]) % 24, // in case of a bad time format entered manually by the user
    minute: int.parse(time.split(":")[1]) % 60,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This might seems hectic for newcomers or beginners, but you can easily convert String to `DateTime` and then `DateTime` to `TimeOfDay` using a specialized constructor, detailed [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/TimeOfDay.fromDateTime.html).

---

Follow these steps for seamless conversion without messing anything up:

1. add this package to `pubspec.yaml` : [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

> This package is necessary to convert any date string to a valid DateTime object.

2. Convert your date string to a `DateTime` object like this way:

> `DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("h:mm a").parse(placement.startTime);`
>
> `TimeOfDay timeOfDay = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(dateTime)`

There you have it. But don't forget to change your `DateFormat` String accordingly. For me, my date string was `4:30 AM`, so my `DateFormat` string was `"h:mm a"`. Change the `DateFormat` String as you need it to be. For `DateFormat` String references, follow this [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay(hour: s.split(":")[0], minute: s.split(":")[1]);
```

`s` is the string you wanna convert.

Comment: argument_type_not_assignable... TimeOfDay parameters should be int. I would edit your answer, but then it will be the same as the current leading answer. So please consider removing your answer

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED SOLUTION AUGUST 26, 2020**

I wrote a `function` to convert from the way a standard date `String` is displayed (ex. 7:04 AM) to `TimeOfDay`.

```
TimeOfDay timeConvert(String normTime) {
    int hour;
    int minute;
    String ampm = normTime.substring(normTime.length - 2);
    String result = normTime.substring(0, normTime.indexOf(' '));
    if (ampm == 'AM' && int.parse(result.split(":")[1]) != 12) {
      hour = int.parse(result.split(':')[0]);
      if (hour == 12) hour = 0;
      minute = int.parse(result.split(":")[1]);
    } else {
      hour = int.parse(result.split(':')[0]) - 12;
      if (hour <= 0) {
        hour = 24 + hour;
      }
      minute = int.parse(result.split(":")[1]);
    }
    return TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
  }
```

All you have to do is pass in your normal time (ex. 12:14 PM) and it'll return a TimeOfDay with the correct time and am/pm.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a static utility function

```
static TimeOfDay parseTimeOfDay(String t) {
    DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").parse(t);
    return TimeOfDay(hour: dateTime.hour, minute: dateTime.minute);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for AM/PM

```
TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay(hour:int.parse(string.split(":")[0]),minute: int.parse(string.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. This will convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time.

```
getTime(String time) {
  TimeOfDay _startTime = TimeOfDay(
      hour: int.parse(time.split(":")[0]),
      minute: int.parse(time.split(":")[1]));
  return "${_startTime.hourOfPeriod}:${_startTime.minute} ${_startTime.period == DayPeriod.pm ? "P.M" : "A.M"}";
}
```

Input = 15:48:00
output= 03:48 P.M

Answer (score 0):

I have got an excellent way to implement TimeofDay Class & using this class can format Time as I want. Here is an example.

**Code:**

```
String getTime(BuildContext context) async {

    final TimeOfDay? time = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (time != null) {
      String am_pm = '';
      if(time.hour < 12 ){
        am_pm = 'AM';
      }
      else{
        am_pm = 'PM';
      }
      return '${time.hourOfPeriod} : ${time.hour} $am_pm' ;
    }
  }
```

**This Code will pop as a Time Select DialogBox & form that we can get our Time.**

**Screenshot:**

[image: Time Picker Popup Screen]

[image: Time After getting Time From TimePicker]