# How to format TimeOfDay to String in flutter

Tags: date, flutter, dart, time, formatting

I want to display the current time.
Used TimeOfDay.Now() to get the current time,

`TimeOfDay _currentTime = TimeOfDay.now();`

`Text("Current Time: ${_currentTime.toString()}")`

Used Text() widget to display time, but it displays TimeOfDay(22.30) instead of 10.30pm.

How to remove TimeOfDay from TimeOfDay(22.30), want to display only 10.30pm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String to TimeOfDay in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382971/how-to-convert-string-to-timeofday-in-flutter)

Comment: no, i want to display the current time 10.30, but it's shows TimeOfDay(10.30).

Comment: want to remove TimeOfDay

Answer (score 42):

Doing a `toString` to a `TimeOfDay` object will return you the default implementation of `toString` which as per documentation:

> Returns a string representation of this object.

What are you looking for here is to `format` it instead.

```dart
TimeOfDay _currentTime = TimeOfDay.now();
Text("Current Time: ${_currentTime.format(context)}")
```

Please also take a look at the official documentation in order to have a better understanding of why `toString` is not doing what you expect.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html

Comment: API changed, now do not use .format(context)

Comment: Umm? The doc is not updated then? I can see still that the suggested method is `format`.

Answer (score 8):

```
'${_currentTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${_currentTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
   if(pickedTime != null ){
      String formattedTime = '${pickedTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${pickedTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
```

It is not crashing and it formats with HH:mm

[image: screenshot]